# How do I make vim to show line on their pair tag?

Tags: vim

Like in other text editor, they have a line for their pair tag like this:

```
 <div>
|  <div>
| |  <div>
| | | <p>Something</p>
| |  </div>
|  </div>
 </div>
```

How do I enable it?
Thanks,

Comment: FWIW, those lines are not related in any way with tags or pairs of tags. They show indentation level.

Comment: Oh really? I didn't know that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on whether you use tab or spaces you have two options:

- using tabs: `set list listchars=tab:\|\ \`  (see `:help 'listchars'`)
- using spaces: you can use this [plugin](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine)

Comment: i didn't knew that the indent isn't related to pair tag. I already follow your guide, sorry for late reply. Thank you! :D